# yii 2 customize column with form field for editing with GridView widget

Tags: gridview, yii2

I want the line column values in a form field so the value can be edited. I'm not trying to override the value in the database. Just want it to be editable for immediate printing.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],



        'home_team',
        'away_team',
        'line',
        'over_under',
        'home_fd',

    ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify *value* and *format* params of the [DataColumn](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/grid/DataColumn.php#L59):

```
[
    'attribute' => 'home_team',
    'value' => function($model){
        return Html::textInput('', $model->home_team);
    },
    'format' => 'raw'
],
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why would the td cell would double in size when i appy your solution.

Comment: maybe because of input size. try to change it's width with css

Comment: I was able to fix size. Thanks for your help. Maybe you can help me with another problem. I want too add a column that would allow me to delete the row from view. I just started working my way through using jquery

Comment: add `['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],` to your `columns` array. I'm answering here, but for the future, if you want to ask something different, please, create a new question

Answer (score 0):

you can "override" the serialColumn class.

Follow an example:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\grid\SerialColumn;
use yii\helpers\Html;

protected function renderDataCellContent($model, $key, $index)
  {
    return Html::input('text','ida', parent::renderDataCellContent($model, $key, $index));
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
No need to replicate code, better call the parent!